# What type are the exceptions or errors in Scala?

Tags: scala

Errors or Exceptions are represented by the Nothing type from my understanding in Scala, but however they can be any type since they are subtype of all types, hence why they are able to work in any method or function. When the error or exception is returned from the method would it be the datatype of the what the method/function returns or the just Nothing type?

Comment: They’re not subtypes of all types. You can’t just return an error. There’s a difference between throwing an exception and returning a value. A throw statement can be of any type because it’s not actually returning a value, it’s stopping the program (unless you catch it)

Comment: "There’s a difference between throwing an exception and returning a value." – This is very simplistic. "A throw statement can be of any type because it’s not actually returning a value, it’s stopping the program" – It is not returning a value, that is correct. It is, however, also not returning at all, and there is a type for expressions that don't return, and that type is called `Nothing`, which is the *bottom type* in Scala, which means precisely that it is the subtype of all types.

Comment: The OP is confused between the type of an exception (which is some subclass of `Throwable`) and the type of a `throw` expression, which is `Nothing`, but your comment does not really clear up this confusion, unfortunately.

Answer (score 8):

`Error` and `Exception` are **not** represented by `Nothing` type - their type is, respectively, `Error` and `Exception`:

```
class Exception extends Throwable
class Error extends Throwable
```

An expression that [throws](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#throw-expressions) is of type `Nothing`. For example, consider why the type of the following expression is `Int`

```
if (true) 42 else throw new Exception
```

The type of expression `42` is `Int`, whilst the type of expression `throw new Exception` is `Nothing`, and the least upper bound of `Int` and `Nothing` is `Int`

```
implicitly[Int <:< Int]      // 42
implicitly[Nothing <:< Int]  // throw new Exception
```

therefore the type of the whole expression is `Int`. Same reasoning applies to

```
if (true) 42 else throw new Error
```

Consider the return type of the following methods

```
def foo(): Error = new Error
def foo(): Nothing = throw new Error
def foo(): Int = if (true) 42 else throw new Exception
def foo(): Any = if (true) 42 else new Exception
```

Note how when `Error` is not thrown it is simply considered like any other regular type.